# Need some advice on a lawn full of weed

Tags: weed-control, yard

I just purchased a house here in Central Texas and looks like the lawn was not cared for what so ever. Filled with weeds and random vegetation, it is an eye sore to look at. I have attached pictures for reference. This is my first house and I dont know where to go and whom to ask. I called a lawn mowing/lawn care and they were not helpful one bit.
My question:
what professional should I hire?
can I do something myself ?
should these weeds to pulled out manually or should I apply some herbicide ?

Any help would be really much appreciated.[image: yard photo]

[image: another yard phyet another yard photooto]

Comment: Doesn't look that bad... I would take a day off and use a [Dutch hoe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuN0A7txcqQ) for example.

Comment: Start watering and mowing. Many weeds can't survive regular mowing, but grass can. In my locale, I could water and mow a bare dirt lot and eventually it would become a nice lawn.

Answer (score 3):

The most common grass in TX is St Augustine . It is put in by sod or plugs , plugs will fill in during one good growing season. Because it is a backyard I would hire someone to put in plugs instead of the cost of sod. The shade will not get the best growth from St Augustine, so it may take two years to fill in . When I got a new house in the Houston area I did nothing with the existing weeds except to mow them short and the grass filled in well. Check with neighbors about what grows well and a good yard maintenance company.